# Nested Panels / Toolbars in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to create a constant bottom toolbar, which controls a panel above it. Then the panel above it should have a toolbar of its own (at the top). I've attempted the below code, which almost works, but I can't see the html of the sub-page inner panels. I think it's because the panel isn't taking up the remaining height, but I don't know why.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {


    // Sub-page sections
    var blah = {
        style: "background-color: #B22222; color:#FF0000;",
        title: "one",
        html: "Why can't I see this html",
        layout:"fit",
        flex: 1
    };
    var blah2 = {
        style: "background-color: #404040; color:#000000;",
        title: "one",
        html: "Why can't I see this html",
        layout:"fit",
        flex: 1
    };  

    // Main portion of the page, which includes top toolbar and content
    var page1 = new Ext.TabPanel({
        dock: "bottom",
        layout: "card",
        items: [blah, blah2, blah],
        title: "one",
        flex: 1
    });

    // This is the outer panel with the bottom toolbar
    var wrapper = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        items: page1,
        dockedItems: [
          {
            xtype: "toolbar",
            dock: "bottom",
            items: [
              {
                iconMask: true,
                iconCls: "download"
              },
              {
                iconMask: true,
                iconCls: "favorites"
              },
              {
                iconMask: true,
                iconCls: "search"
              },
              {
                iconMask: true,
                iconCls: "user"
              }
            ]  
          }
        ]
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that I'm trying to nest the panels so that the bottom toolbar will remain docked even as the other panels change / transition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to do can be done using a TabPanel, rather than a Toolbar. When you dock the tabBar to the bottom, each tabButton can accept an icon.

I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, but this should help:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {


        // Sub-page sections
        var blah = {
            style: "background-color: #B22222; color:#FF0000;",
            title: "one",
            html: "Why can't I see this html",
        };
        var blah2 = {
            style: "background-color: #404040; color:#000000;",
            title: "one",
            html: "Why can't I see this html",
        };  

        // Main portion of the page, which includes top toolbar and content
        var page1 = new Ext.TabPanel({
            items: [blah, blah2, blah],
            title: "one",
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: "download",
        });

        // This is the outer panel with the bottom toolbar
        var wrapper = new Ext.TabPanel({
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            },
            items: [
                page1,
                {
                    iconMask: true,
                    iconCls: "favorites"
                },
                {
                    iconMask: true,
                    iconCls: "search"
                },
                {
                    iconMask: true,
                    iconCls: "user"
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

I made a screencast about [building a user interface in sencha touch using tabs and toolbars](http://vimeo.com/22251762). There's a [live demo](http://sencha-tabs.heroku.com/), and the [code is on github](https://github.com/nelstrom/Sencha-Touch-tabs-and-toolbars-demo), so feel free to use that as a reference.

Comment: Thank you! And also thank you for the video tutorials. I've already watched each of them multiple times, trying to figure this (and other things) out. I'm still a noob, but I'd be completely lost without those videos.

Comment: While I have you (if you're still around), do you know when / which book I could purchase to learn more? I can't spend the few thousand for training, but I'm willing to put in the time. How much could I learn from Ext JS that would be applicable to Sencha Touch?

Comment: Oh, actually, I missed that video. I didn't realize there were more than those listed on this page: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Sencha_Touch

Comment: Sencha Touch has a lot in common with Ext JS, so until a book about Touch comes along, your best bet is probably to read a book on Ext JS. Here's the full list of my [Sencha Touch screencasts](http://bit.ly/senchacasts). By the way, the one on tabs and toolbars was only published yesterday, so I'm not surprised you hadn't seen it yet!

Comment: It's only in the bottom that the tab panel accepts icons? I changed the position to left but I loose the icons, please could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317452/how-do-i-keep-the-images-when-changing-tabbar-position  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

take the

`layout: "card",`

out of the page1 TabPanel, and place it in the wrapper Panel instead