# How do I keep the images when changing tabbar position?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sass

Hi I would like to know how to keep the icnClass when I set the tab to the left as so:

```
Ext.define("GS.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],

config: {
    tabBarPosition:'left',
    scrollable: true,

    styleHtmlContent: false,

    items: [
     {
        xtype: 'panelhome'  
     },
     {
        xtype: 'contactform'
     },
     {
        xtype: 'blog'
     }
    ]
}
});

Ext.define("GS.view.Blog",{
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype:'blog',

config:{
    title:'Blog',
    iconCls:'bolt',             

    items:{
        xtype:'list',
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        title: 'Recent Posts',

        store:{
            autoLoad:true,
            fields: ['title','author', 'content'],

            proxy:{
                type:'jsonp',
                url:'...',
                reader: {
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed via sass. Look into the following elements

```
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-left .x-tab-active .x-button-icon {}
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-left .x-tab .x-button-icon {}
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-left .x-tab-active {}
.x-tabbar.x-docked-left .x-tab .x-button-icon {}
.x-tabbar.x-docked-left .x-tab{}
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-left .x-tab-active .x-button-icon {}
.x-tab .x-button-icon.home, .x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.home {}
```